# R studio youtubecaption

Tags: r

the package youtubecaption was working perfectly, but now it returns the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Need to install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/.
Error in system2(conda, args = c("info", "--json"), stdout = TRUE, stderr = FALSE) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'D:\Conda\condabin\conda.bat info --json'
```

I don't even understand why is it related to anaconda...
The code is:

```
library(youtubecaption)
a <- get_caption("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7Kq5w_3AfY")
```

Comment: It's related because it uses python under the hood.

Comment: How do i solve it? i have anaconda installed and it didn't solve

Comment: Is python installed?

Comment: yes, evertithing was working properly, i honestly don't know what is happening

Comment: Contact the maintainer? I'm not sure I can help any more than that.